# Johnson property

Tags: model-theory

I have seen this formula at our university blackboard: $$\kappa\to(\lambda,\mu)$$
under the name Johnsosn conjecture. Not sure about the spelling.
Can someone give me a reference what that meant ?

Comment: Maybe [Jónsson cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B3nsson_cardinal)  named after [Bjarni Jónsson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarni_J%C3%B3nsson)

Comment: Look for infinitary combinatory on Wikipedia. A main example of this formula is Erdős–Dushnik–Miller theorem.

Comment: Related: [Chang's conjecture](https://books.google.it/books?id=DLCyehuI0i0C&pg=PA915&lpg=PA915)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I remember the Chang's cojecture from the book Model Theoretic Logics by Barwise Feferman bu I cannot find it there. Any hint ?